# AWS DynamoDB Naming Convention

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a naming convention for different objects in DynamoDB, such as tables, partition and sort keys, LSIs, GSIs, attributes, etc. I read a lot of articles and there is no common way to do that but want to learn from real-time examples to choose which one will fit best our needs.

The infrastructure I am working on is based on microservices. Along with this, some of our development environments share the same AWS account. Based on this, I ended up with something like this:

```
Tables: [Environment].[Service Name].[Table Name].ddb-table
GSIs/LSIs: [Environment].[Service Name].[Table Name].[GSI/LSI Name].ddb-[gsi/lsi]
Partition Key: pk ??? (in my understanding, the keys should have abstract names, because the single table stores versatile data in the same key)
Sort Key: sk ??? (in my understanding, the keys should have abstract names, because the single table stores versatile data in the same key)
Attributes: meaningful but as short as possible as they are kept for every item in the table
```

- Different elements are separated by dot (.)
- All names are separated by dashes (kebab-case) and in lower case
- Tables/GSIs/LSIs are in singular form

Here is an example:

```
Table: dev.user-service.user-order.ddb-table
LSI: dev.user-service.user-order.lsi1pk.ddb-lsi
GSI: dev.user-service.user-order.gsi1pk.ddb-gsi
```

What naming conventions do you follow?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My advice:

- Use PK and SK as your partition key and sort key.
- Don't put table names into code. Use ParameterStore. For example, if you ever do a table restore it will be to a new table name, and if you want to send traffic to the new name you'll not want to change code.
- Thus don't get too fixed to any particular table name. Never try to have code predict a table name. Only have them be consistent to help humans.
- Don't put regions in your table names. When you switch to Global Tables they all keep the same name. Awkward!
- GSIs can be called GSI1, GSI2, etc. GSI keys are GSI1PK and GSI1SK, etc.
- Tag your tables with their name if you ever want to track per-table costs later.
- Short yet meaningful attribute names are nice because it reduces storage and can reduce RCU/WCU if you're near the 4kb or 1kb lines.
- Use difference accounts for dev, staging, and production. If you want to put the names into tables as well to help you spot "OMG I'm in production" that's fine.
- If you have lots of attributes as the item payload which aren't used for GSIs or filtering and are always returned together, consider just storing them as a string or binary which gets parsed client side. You can even compress them. It's more efficient and lower latency because it skips the data marshaling.

Comment: could you provide us a link in order to know the naming convention or a more formal way to handle the name for dynamo

Comment: Can you be more specific? I gave advice above.

Comment: Get it, and thank you for that, but I'm looking for formal suggestions. ( Aws suggestions, another company suggestions )  in order to provide that documentation as support.

Comment: You can find some BP guidance here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html